# How to fix a self-turning handle on a Price-Pfister single handled faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a  Price-Pfister 533 Genesis single handled kitchen faucet that turns itself off.  It is impossible to run water at a low volume because the moment your hand is off the handle it shuts off.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pfister is so aware of this problem they have a video on the problem http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/about/falling_handle.aspx

Turns out they made a faucets with heavy metal handles but cheap plastic internal parts... after a few years they fail.  I called up customer service, identified myself as an original owner, gave an approximate date of purchase, and was sent new parts.

They sent me a new metal nut, Pfister part 941-7110 . Then, they sent a new chromed plastic handle that has less mass.

Comment: +1, perfect fix, I actually have the same problem with one, so I'm gonna take your advise.  thanks.

Comment: you must state that you are the original buyer of the part. They said they are sending a new cartridge that holds the handle.

Comment: I have had to replace the cartridge twice since 2008. Each time PP has sent a replacement cartridge and brass nut.

Comment: After the third round, PP sent me an entirely new faucet. Sadly, a cheap Phirst model, that quite frankly is not built to the standard of the original.